# Delete file if found

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a batch script with a line like this:

```
del "%TARGET_DIR%\packages.config"
```

But if `packages.config` does not exist in the target directory it produces an error.

> Could Not Find `\\...\packages.config`

Is there a command line switch `del` that will prevent raising an error the target file is not found? I'm open to using an `if exists` if I have to, but I have a number of similar commands, and I'd like to avoid having to do that for every single file I might want to delete.

Comment: FYI, `DEL /Q` does not allow it to silently fail; it still complains. You're going to have to test ahead of time... sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could functionalize your `IF EXISTS/DEL` calls so that the code isn't repeated a ton; for doing faux functions in DOS, [see this](http://dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php).

They use GOTO statements to implement functions, but it should work the same.

From that page:

**Example Function:**

```
:myDosFunc    - here starts my function identified by it`s label
echo. here the myDosFunc function is executing a group of commands
echo. it could do a lot of things
GOTO:EOF
```

**Calling the function:**

```
call:myDosFunc
```

For usage on IF EXISTS, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022176/how-to-verify-if-a-file-exists-in-a-windows-bat-file).

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect `stderr` to null:

```
del "%TARGET_DIR%\packages.config" 2> nul
```

[ref](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going with the other answer because I don't want to ignore *all* errors (e.g. if the file is in use), just if the file is not found.